# useEffect does not run in initial render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In `Piano` component I am getting window's dimensions using a hook (`useWindowDimensions()`). In `useEffect`, I want to render component everytime width of window changes.

It re-renders the component everytime width changes (because `keyData` depends on it and it is in `dependencyList`) but does not render in initial render. **So component does not render until I resize the window**.

Following code is `Piano` component.

```
const svgRef = React.useRef(null);
const svgEl = d3.select(svgRef.current);

const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
const height = width / 4;

const keyData = generateKeyData(88, width);

React.useEffect(() => {
  svgEl.selectAll("*").remove();
  generatePianoNode(svgEl, keyData);
}, [svgEl, keyData]);

return (
  <svg ref={ svgRef } width={ width } height={ height } />
);
```

I tried to put another useEffect hook with empty dependency list with the same code but it also didn't work.

Comment: What is your component returning ?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: The answer below sums it up well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The useEffect hook actually renders on initial component mount but the problem here is that the way you generate piano node .

You need to somehow put the value in a state and update state so the component re-renders everytime the state changes and also when the component mounts .

```
const [value , setValue ] = React.useState("1")

React.useEffect(() => {
  // your logic
  // setValue("2")
}, [value]);
```

Now the useEffect hook will run on component mount and then everytime the state value changes .

***Note***

If the value change simultaneously it will cause rendering problem in the component so a better option in this case is assigning an event listener in useEffect like this :

```
const handleScroll = () => {
 // your logic
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
    window.addEventListener("scroll" , handleScroll)
  } 
  return () => {
     // on component unmount remove event listener
     if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
       window.removeEventListener("scroll" , handleScroll)
     } 
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: I think I have to put `generatePianoNode` to a state and then add it to dependencyList, right?

Comment: @BatınEvirgen Yes based on your logic place anything in useEffect brackets that you want useEffect to run when they change .

Comment: It works but it gives a `Maximum update depth exceeded.` warning in console. It is probably I'm calling `setValue` inside `useEffect` which has `value` in it's dependencies. Is there another workaround?

Comment: @BatınEvirgen If you change the value simultaneously it will throw an error , you may need to use an event listener and assign a custom function .